# Display the number of question for tag synonyms in the tag search, or indicate it is a tag synonym

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-search

For example, the tag [washing](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/washing) is a synonym of [cleaning](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) on https://cooking.stackexchange.com, but when searching for `washing` on https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags it says the tag has 0 questions (vs. 337 questions for cleaning):

[image] [image]

It might be clearer to display the number of question for tag synonyms in the tag search, or indicate in the tag search result page that it is a tag synonym.